# Collection values unexpectedly change to highest value in collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a validation function which runs validation on a range given as a parameter.

I have a class which is a validation object which has the row number and column number.

If there is a blank cell the details of the details of the cell are added to the 
ValidationError object, which is then added to the collection.

The values of the collection however, change at the end of the function

Below is the validation code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    CellValidation (Sheets(1).range("A1:C11"))

End Sub

Public Function CellValidation(range As range)
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Column As Long
    Dim arraySize As Long
    Dim l_currentRow As Long
    Dim l_boolRowInvalid As Boolean
    Dim l_validationError As New ValidationError
    Dim l_validationErrors As New Collection
    Dim l_error As Variant

    l_boolRowInvalid = False
    l_currentRow = 1
    arraySize = 0
    Set sheet = range.Worksheet

    With sheet
        'Loop through rows
        For Row = 1 To 11
            'Loop through columns
            For Column = 1 To 3
                With range

                    'Check for blank or null cell
                    If VarType(.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = 0 Or VarType(.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = 1 Then
                        l_boolRowInvalid = True
                    End If

                End With

                If l_boolRowInvalid = True Then

                    l_validationError.Row = Row
                    l_validationError.Column = Column

                    l_validationErrors.Add l_validationError

                    l_boolRowInvalid = False

                    arraySize = arraySize + 1
                    'If I debug here I get my expected values
                    Debug.Print l_validationErrors(arraySize).Row & "," & l_validationErrors(arraySize).Column & " "
                End If

            Next Column
                l_currentRow = l_currentRow + 1
                DoEvents
        Next Row

    End With
    'However when I check the values of the collection here the values have all changed
    Debug.Print "Second Test"
    For Each l_error In l_validationErrors
        Debug.Print l_error.Row & "," & l_error.Column & " "
    Next

End Function
```

Below is the ValidationError Class

```
Public Row As Long
Public Column As Integer
```

Below is the excel sheet

[image: Excel sheet]

Below is the output given by the program:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trying this code

```
Public Function CellValidation(range As range)
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Column As Long
    Dim arraySize As Long
    Dim l_currentRow As Long
    Dim l_boolRowInvalid As Boolean
    Dim l_validationError As ValidationError
    Dim l_validationErrors As New Collection
    Dim l_error As Variant

    l_boolRowInvalid = False
    l_currentRow = 1
    arraySize = 0
    Set sheet = range.Worksheet

    With sheet
        'Loop through rows
        For Row = 1 To 11
            'Loop through columns
            For Column = 1 To 3
                With range

                    'Check for blank or null cell
                    If VarType(.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = 0 Or VarType(.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = 1 Then
                        l_boolRowInvalid = True
                    End If

                End With

                If l_boolRowInvalid = True Then
                    Set l_validationError = New ValidationError
                    l_validationError.Row = Row
                    l_validationError.Column = Column

                    l_validationErrors.Add l_validationError

                    l_boolRowInvalid = False

                    arraySize = arraySize + 1
                    'If I debug here I get my expected values
                    Debug.Print l_validationErrors(arraySize).Row & "," & l_validationErrors(arraySize).Column & " "
                End If

            Next Column
                l_currentRow = l_currentRow + 1
                DoEvents
        Next Row

    End With
    'However when I check the values of the collection here the values have all changed
    Debug.Print "Second Test"
    For Each l_error In l_validationErrors
        Debug.Print l_error.Row & "," & l_error.Column & " "
    Next

End Function
```

You need to create a new instance of l_validationError within the for loop otherwise only one instance of l_validationError will be created and you only change this instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance, @Storax. This worked perfectly.